# Is there a shorthand notation that can replace an expression with $0$ if the expression is undefined?

Tags: notation

I'm trying to write an expression for a certain operation on a matrix (namely, adding a row full of zeros) that I can use as part of a big ugly self-contained definition. Using the implicit $\mathbf{X}_{i,j} = f(i,j)$ notation, this is what I had, originally...

$$\left[\mathbf{X}_{i,j}\right]_{m\times n}\mapsto\left[\mathbf{X}_{i,j}\right]_{(m+1)\times n}$$

... until I noticed that when $i=m+1$, $\mathbf{X}_{i,j}$ does not have a defined value, and isn't necessarily zero by default. But I like to cover my bases. So, to make sure every entry is defined, I did this.

$$\left[\mathbf{X}_{i,j}\right]_{m\times n}\mapsto\left[\begin{cases}\mathbf{X}_{i,j}&\text{if }i\leq m\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\right]_{(m+1)\times n}$$

Now, since in my case, I'm actually adding and subtracting other things from each entry (including the ones in the new row), I find this in-expression piecewise notation to be quite ugly. I realise I could just invent some notation like putting a tilde over the $\mathbf{X}$ and use the piecewise expression outside of the main equation to define it, but I like to put these things in one big expression. So, what I want to know is this:

Is there a reasonably common, clean notation that could help me represent "$\mathbf{X}_{i,j}$, but $0$ if it's undefined"? If not, is there a neater expression I could use in the place of that piecewise one? Or perhaps just some simple notation for matrices that would be easily understood as "$\mathbf{X}$, with an additional row of zeros"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or perhaps just some simple notation for matrices that would be easily understood as "$\mathbf X$, with an additional row of zeros"?

I would suggest a [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix):

$$ \mathbf X \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf X \\ \mathbf 0_{1\times n} \end{bmatrix} $$

---

In situations that are too complicated for using block matrices as a shortcut, the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) would provide a fairly compact notation:
$$ (X_{ij})_{m\times n} \mapsto \bigl([i\le m]X_{ij}\bigr)_{(m+1)\times n} $$
It is a common convention that the Iverson bracket produces a "strong zero" that overrides the undefinedness of whatever it's multiplied with. On the other hand, the Iverson bracket *itself* is not in so common use that you can just start using it without first explaining to your reader that that's what you're doing.

Comment: Ah, I'd somehow missed that convention on the Wikipedia article. Does that same convention apply to similar notations like the Kronecker delta?

Comment: @bjshnog: I'd expect it would probably be understood there too.